# Class not found in module

Tags: kotlin

I made a project using kotlin:

```
Group id-> com.programming.kotlin

Artifact id->chapter01

Module name->chapter01

package->com.programming.kotlin.chapter01
```

I made a  kotlin class called Program.kt

The problem is: when i try to make a new class(called Program2.kt) inside package and when i try to run it ,i got this error:

```
class com.programming.kotlin.chapter01.Program2kt not found in module 'chapter01_main'
```

My question is:
how to allow any new class other than Main class to run inside intellij ?

Comment: Did you include `package com.programming.kotlin.chapter01` into `Program2.kt`?

Comment: yes,it's included

Comment: The is obviously something wrong with your classpath. Please add some more information: Gradle-script, how you run the application, how you build the application.

Comment: try to invalidate and restart

Comment: hey author did you solved that issue?

Comment: i'd had the same problem, right-click on the .kt file and then click on "Run", hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your class name should be `com.programming.kotlin.chapter01.Program2`. If you go to InteliJ and right click on the class, you can click `Copy Reference`, which will copy the class reference (package and class name).

The Kt (with a capital K) is only added to functions without an enclosing class or object.

Comment: whey should by the  class name  `com.programming.kotlin.chapter01.Program2` ?